# Can I use GPGS in an app that isn't a game?

Tags: android, google-play-games

I'm only asking this as a fresh question because I couldn't find existing questions asking exactly this. I have [a WIP app](https://www.wopple.in/), wherein I want to implement achievements for users. I don't plan to have a huge number of achievements, but still, Google Play Games Services seems like a familiar and convenient option, especially for Android.

Now [the Achievements page on the Google Developers website](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/achievements) says:

> Achievements can be a great way to increase your users' engagement within your **game**.

Most, if not all, references are to *games* and not apps in general. I would like to know for sure whether it is good practice to implement Achievements through GPGS in Android apps that aren't games. Any official links confirming so would be highly appreciated.

Apologies in advance, if this has already been asked before.